# django self join query using aliases

Tags: sql, django, orm, django-queryset

am trying to use queryset to perform the following query without using raw SQL. any idea how can do that?

```
select * from category_main a, category_list b, category_main c where b.main_id=c.id and a.id=c.parent_id
```

**UPDATED**

below are my models

```
class Main(models.Model):
    slug       = models.SlugField()
    is_active  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    site       = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    parent     = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to={'parent' : None})
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("slug", "parent"))
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug

class List(models.Model):
    main        = models.ForeignKey(Main)
    slug        = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    parent      = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug
```

**UPDATE**

Hi, I just managed to find a query that does that for me, I used advised below to join main with  main's parent and from there I joined list with main list using the below

```
Main.objects.select_related('main', 'parent').filter(list__is_active=True, maini18n__language='en', list__listi18n__language='en').query.__str__()

'SELECT `category_main`.`id`, `category_main`.`slug`, `category_main`.`is_active`, `category_main`.`site_id`, `category_main`.`parent_id`, T5.`id`, T5.`slug`, T5.`is_active`, T5.`site_id`, T5.`parent_id` FROM `category_main` INNER JOIN `category_maini18n` ON (`category_main`.`id` = `category_maini18n`.`main_id`) INNER JOIN `category_list` ON (`category_main`.`id` = `category_list`.`main_id`) INNER JOIN `category_listi18n` ON (`category_list`.`id` = `category_listi18n`.`list_id`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `category_main` T5 ON (`category_main`.`parent_id` = T5.`id`) WHERE (`category_maini18n`.`language` = en  AND `category_list`.`is_active` = True  AND `category_listi18n`.`language` = en )'
```

the returned query mapped everything I need, accept its not being added to the select statement, is there a way so i can force it to select columns from category_list.* ?

Comment: putting your models in your question will help get a better answer!

Comment: i just amended my models to the post :)

Comment: you see? with the models you got the answer ;-)

Comment: @Stefano, yeah, it solved 80% of my problem:). Now only remaining to find out how to include the joined table in the select statement

Comment: I can see an `INNER JOIN 'category_list'`, isn't that doing what you want? any request to an element of your query  `qs = Main.objs.sel_related.filter(..)` concerning a `List` object should not hit the database. Please check out the examples in [django doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), and [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) an equality of INNER JOIN and classic SELECT queries

Answer (score 1):

This does basically what you want:

```
lists = List.objects.select_related('main', 'parent')
```

Note you have to explicitly state the relationships to follow in select_related here, because your `parent` relationship has `null=True` which isn't followed by default.

This will give you a set of `List` objects, but pre-fetch the related `Main` and `List` objects which you can reference as normal without hitting the db again.

Comment: but how do i pre-fetch the related Main without hitting the database?

Comment: thanks mate, your answer helped me come up with a good solution based on what you said, I just updated my post with the query i used. I still though trying to include the selected records in the select statement