# django inner join same column different results

Tags: sql, django, json

I think I may have a solution here -

[Django query where in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949986/django-query-where-in)

It's basically approaching my query differently than I have posted below (I hope).

Coming from an SQL background I have a query that looks like so (updated)-

```
SELECT a.jobmst_name AS Parent, b.jobmst_name as Job from jobmst a
    inner join jobmst b on b.jobmst_prntid = a.jobmst_id
    WHERE (a.jobmst_name = 'Dept' and a.jobmst_prntid IS NULL) OR b.jobmst_prntname LIKE '\Dept\%' AND b.jobmst_dirty <> 'X'
UNION
SELECT jobmst_prntname as Parent, jobmst_name as Job FROM jobmst
    WHERE  (jobmst_name = 'Dept' AND jobmst_prntid IS NULL)
```

Which will return a list like the following -

```
Parent                          Job
NULL                            Dept
01. Dept_sub01                  01.01 Trade Recon
02. Dept_sub02                  02.04 Dept_sub02.04
02.04 Dept_sub02.04         02.04.02 Dept_sub02.04
02.04 Dept_sub02.04         02.04.04 Dept_sub02.04
02.04 Dept_sub02.04         02.04.05 Dept_sub02.04
02.04.01 Dept_sub02.04.01   02.04.01.01 Dept_sub02.04.01
02.04.01 Dept_sub02.04.01   02.04.01.02 Dept_sub02.04.01
Dept                            01. Dept_sub01
Dept                            02. Dept_sub02
Dept                            03. Dept_sub03
```

How do I do the following in Django?  The UNION is the easy part so ignore that part of the query.  The important part is as follows -

The jobmst_id is the primary key of the table.  The jobmst_prntid is the the same as the jobmst_id but not in the same row (as seen above).

I'm trying to generate json so that I can do a heirarchy tree but to do that I want my json to be setup like -

{parent_name: Dept, name: Dept01234}, {parent_name: Dept, name: Dept53452}

I've done inner joins on a table but the issue is that I want to tell it that the jobmst_id and jobmst_prntid are both going to give me a value from jobmst_name and it's going to be a different value on each key.

Hope this makes sense.

UPDATE - Found this which explains exactly what I'm trying to do -

[django self join query using aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872894/django-self-join-query-using-aliases)

But it doesn't necessarily explain how to get it to essentially show 'jobmst_name', 'jobmst_name' while giving me the Parent name on one and the child name on the other even though I'm querying the same column.

EDIT - Here is the model I'm dealing with.

```
class Jobmst(models.Model):
    jobmst_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    jobmst_type = models.SmallIntegerField()
    jobmst_prntid = models.IntegerField('self', null=True, blank=True)
    jobmst_active = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    evntmst_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_evntoffset = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_name = models.TextField(blank=True)
    jobmst_mode = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_owner = models.ForeignKey('Owner', db_column='jobmst_owner', related_name = 'Jobmst_Jobmst_owner', blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_desc = models.TextField(blank=True) # This field type is a guess.
    jobmst_crttm = models.DateTimeField()
    jobdtl_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_lstchgtm = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_runbook = models.TextField(blank=True) # This field type is a guess.
    jobcls_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobmst_prntname = models.TextField(blank=True)
    jobmst_alias = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    jobmst_dirty = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.jobmst_name   
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'jobmst'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may get the same problem as I had I found the solution (ie. how to get MPTT working with a legacy database!)

I ran through the beginning of the MPTT tutorial here -

http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/tutorial.html

I then opened my SSMS and looked at how django mptt was creating the table for the test.  I then recreated the columns that were missing in my legacy table -

lft, rght, tree_id, level

as well as the FK/PK connections.

From there I simply had to load up the model in shell -

from polls.models import Jobmst
Jobmst.objects.rebuild()

Bam!  It then created all the values I needed by running through the model.

Now I can do the rest of the tutorial and I can get my tree view output now just need to get it in json so I can import into d3.

If anyone finds this and has questions just msg me.